# dotenv cli dynamically set environment varible from executed command in `package.json` script

Tags: powershell, shell, command-line, package.json, dotenv

I have a simple command like this to run nodejs program with dynamic environment variables set:

```
pnpm exec dotenv -v DATABASE_URL=$(pnpm exec ts-node ./getDatabaseUrl.ts) -- pnpm -C backend run migrate:dev:main
```

It executes `getDatabaseUrl.ts` script and assigns the result to the environment variable using dotenv-cli and then executes next script(`pnpm -C backend run migrate:dev:main`) for which `DATABASE_URL` env var will be available.

And it works perfectly when I run it in **PowerShell 7.3.4**
But when I put it in `package.json` it does not work:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "migrate:dev:main": "pnpm exec dotenv -v DATABASE_URL=$(pnpm exec ts-node ./getDatabaseUrl.ts) -- pnpm -C backend run migrate:dev:main"
  }
}
```

shows such error: `Unexpected argument DATABASE_URL=$(pnpm. Expected variable in format variable=value`
How to make this command work from `package.json` script?
I also tried like this without `pnpm` at the beginning:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "migrate:dev:main": "dotenv -v DATABASE_URL=$(pnpm exec ts-node ./getDatabaseUrl.ts) -- pnpm -C backend run migrate:dev:main"
  }
}
```

but it does not work anyway, error: `-- was unexpected at this time.`
or like this(similar error):

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "migrate:dev:main": "dotenv -v DATABASE_URL=$(pnpm exec ts-node ./getDatabaseUrl.ts) pnpm -C backend run migrate:dev:main"
  }
}
```

error: `pnpm was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: how this is related to Powershell? Shouldn't this be a "node.js" question?

Comment: @strongline script is executed in powershell, `$(...)` - operator from powershell too. There is nothing related to node.js except `package.json` which I included as a tag. So it should not be a "node.js" question.

Comment: since this is within package.json, this has everything with nodejs. How it handles/intepret script block inside, whether any escaping character is required etc. I'd think that for node.js engine, it doesn't even know that the hosting terminal is powershell to begin with.

Comment: @strongline https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#exiting as you see it is just a line passed to `sh` command...

Comment: And for Windows it is using CMD: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-run-script#script-shell which has nothing to do with node.js in such case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default script shell of `npm` is `cmd.exe` ([source](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#script-shell)).

You are probably using this default, because `$(...)` does not get evaluated. You can solve your problem in multiple ways:

1. Change your script shell to `pwsh` ([docs](https://pnpm.io/cli/run#script-shell)):

   ```
   pnpm config set script-shell "pwsh"
   ```

   Use an absolute path, if `pwsh` is not in your path, e. g. `"C:\\path\\to\\pwsh.exe"`
2. Execute your command with PowerShell *explicitly*. That will work in both script shells, `cmd` and `pwsh`/`powershell`:

   ```json
   {
     "scripts": {
       "migrate:dev:main": "pwsh -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoProfile -Command \"pnpm exec dotenv -v DATABASE_URL=$(pnpm exec ts-node ./getDatabaseUrl.ts) -- pnpm -C backend run migrate:dev:main\""
     }
   }
   ```